# Quarkus - Dependencies not included in uber jar - JVM mode

Tags: java, quarkus

I have the a quarkus project created with "amazon-lambda, resteasy, jackson. and gson" libraries. I have a StreamLambdaHandler implementing the RequestStreamHandler. I am running the application in JVM mode.

I have the below property added in `application.properties`:

```
quarkus.package.uber-jar=true
```

I am using the thin `jar` named `code-with-quarkus-1-runner.jar`.

Sending a JSON POST request from API gateway is giving below exception. Please let me know what could be the issue.

```
Error loading class org.test.StreamLambdaHandler: com/google/gson/JsonElement:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonElement
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.JsonElement. Current
classpath: file:/var/task/
```

**Expected behavior**
the gson libraries should have been copied in the uber jar and should not have thrown any exceptions

**Actual behavior:**
Sending a JSON POST request from API gateway is giving below exception. Please let me know what could be the issue.

```
Error loading class org.test.StreamLambdaHandler: com/google/gson/JsonElement:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonElement
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.JsonElement
Current classpath: file:/var/task/
```

Below is my `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.acme</groupId>
  <artifactId>code-with-quarkus</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-universe-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.0.2.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.package.type>uber-jar</quarkus.package.type>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-amazon-lambda</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <parameters>${maven.compiler.parameters}</parameters>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                  </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <properties>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Also, please find below for the RequestStreamHandler class code:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class StreamLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        JsonObject responseJson = new JsonObject();
        JsonObject responseBody = new JsonObject();
        responseBody.addProperty("message", "New item created");
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
        writer.write(responseJson.toString());
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The correct entry with Quarkus 2 is `quarkus.package.type=uber-jar`.

Comment: @Codo I tried using quarkus.package.type=uber-jar as well and it didn't create a uber-jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be with the way Quarkus is building the fat/uber jar when quarkus-amazon-lambda dependency is added. With this dependency added, fat jar is not created even if we explicitly ask it to create using application properties (quarkus.package.type=uber-jar) and using ./mvnw package -Dquarkus.package.type=uber-jar command.

The only way for creating lambda function in these cases seem to be to upload function.zip file that gets created during build process or using the native image. No fat jar option.

I am not sure if this is a bug and will raise it in Quarkus github community.

Zip file had all the dependencies required added, but is much larger is size than what I was expecting it to.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your project setup but did you reference all your resources like this:

```xml
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>**/application.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

If you have other resources you would add a additional *resource*.

Comment: application.properties is under the default location "src/main/resources" for my project as well. But I have tried adding the code you provided in the pom.xml file. I am still getting the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to run a native image it seems that the gson dependency is removed at build time.

The GraalVM responsible for quarkus native builds runs the application at build time and removes everything that it thinks to be unused in the code. This way the resulting image can be much lighter both in size and startup times.

The drawback to this is that it 'weeds out' whole libraries and even methods from your classes that seem to be unused. This is usually the case with third party libraries that does not include a jandex index.

There are [many ways to overcome this](https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips). But the best way is to use the quarkus-flavored version of the libraries if they are available.

It seems that Quarkus project favors Jackson and JsonB, but there is a quarkus-camel version of Gson. Try to replace your gson dependency with this:
https://camel.apache.org/camel-quarkus/latest/reference/extensions/gson.html

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quarkus-gson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thank you. I am running the application in jvm mode. using clean package to generate the uber jar (code-with-quarkus-1-runner.jar). I tried replacing the dependency with the one you suggested. I am still getting the same below exception:

com/google/gson/JsonObject: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonObject
 at org.test.StreamLambdaHandler.handleRequest(StreamLambdaHandler.java:27)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

I also have updated the question with streamhandler code now.

Comment: Hmm, I  noticed that you included jackson, from the `quarkus-resteasy-jackson` package, not sure if any compatibility problems would arise from this, but since the problem is with gson, maybe as a quick fix, you could try to inject the a Jackson ObjectMapper and exclude gson entirely. I also often use the Vert.X's Json implementation with a nice and clean API. It comes built in with Quarkus (since the core is Vert.X) https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/json/Json.html

Comment: Just realized that the built in vertx Json implementation already has the same JsonObject  that even has the same API that you have posted in the example. So all you need to do is to delete the Gson dependency and use this import:  `import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;`. There also seems to be a duplication in the example wheret the responseBody is modified but the responseObject is written.

Comment: I removed the gson dependencies completely and used vertx libraries and also writing responseBody now. Now getting the below error. I have a feeling the jar  is not getting packaged correctly. I tried using jar with the name "code-with-quarkus-1-runner.jar" (I believe this is the uber jar but not sure now) which was 312KB and other jar "code-with-quarkus-1.jar" which was 3KB. Please suggest what could be the issue.

io/vertx/core/json/JsonObject: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/vertx/core/json/JsonObject
Current classpath: file:/var/task/

Comment: You could look into the jar or have maven list the runtime dependencies that end up in the jar, with: https://quarkus.io/guides/maven-tooling#logging-quarkus-application-build-classpath-tree

Comment: also, have you tried the correct application property as suggested by @Codo? If not, it might be the case that they are not packed in the jar, and by default Quarkus does not pack most of the dependencies into the jar (to optimize docker image building times) and have to be manually copied over with the jar. If you look into the Dockerfiles (src/main/docker) that come with the project by default you can see the copy steps.

Comment: I scanned through the jar and listed the maven dependencies as well. I did not see the dependencies I was looking for

Comment: The issue turned out to be with the way Quarkus is building the fat/uber jar when quarkus-amazon-lambda dependency is added. When added, fat jar is not created even if we explicitly ask it to create using app properties or using ./mvnw package -Dquarkus.package.type=uber-jar command.
The only way for creating lambda function in these cases seem to be to upload function.zip file that gets created during build process. It has all the dependencies required added, but is much larger is size than what I was expecting it to.I am not sure if this is a bug and will raise it in their github community.